# Pandas xlsxwriter : find first empty row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a code which web scraps and returns the data to excel. However, there are more than 1 webpages. The code works but overwrites the data from the previous webpage scrapped. Any help?

```
for i in range(1,4):
   url="https:..."
   response=request.get(url)
   soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text)
   data=soup.find_all("td",{"class"})
   results=[]
   for item in data:
        results.append(item.text)
   writer=pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(results).reshape(20,7),colums=list(abcdefg"))
   df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name-'Sheet1')
   writer.save
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: you want to append the rows or create a new sheet ?

Comment: append the rows

Comment: would you have the code for that please?

Comment: found the answer : http://w3cgeek.com/how-to-write-on-existing-excel-files-without-losing-previous-information-using-python.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way, if you scrap all the pages during the same script execution.

You declare the `writer` before the loop, and a counter too, to keep track of the starting row to append the next dataframe :

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')
count = 0
for i in range(1,4):
   url="https:..."
   response=request.get(url)
   soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text)
   data=soup.find_all("td",{"class"})
   results=[]
   for item in data:
        results.append(item.text)

   df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(results).reshape(20,7),colums=list('abcdefg'))
   df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', startrow=count)
   count += len(results)+1 # +1 for the header

writer.save()  # out of the loop to save only once at the end
```

Comment: still same issue :(

Comment: are you scraping all the pages in the same loop ? by saving the writer at the end, you should be able to keep all data

Comment: yes scrapping all pages in same loop. and hence results prints just the last page scrapped.

Comment: did you move the `writer.save()` back out of the loop ?